# How to retrieve data attribute from select options of a form select menu using stimulus?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I have a select menu that is a stimulus target.  Each option of that select has a custom data attribute.  When that select changes I need the stimulus controller to read a dataset attribute from the selected option...not the select menu target.

In the controller action, event.currentTarget is the select menu where the target attribute is set.  Rather, I expecting it to be the selected option.

```
// this correctly returns the selected options value attribute.  Stimulus must know what you want in this case.
event.currentTarget.value



// However, calling this returns the classList for the target...which is the select, not the option.
event.currentTarget.classList



// And, calling this returns 'undefined' because data-value is not defined on the target select, it's defined on the selected option...which is not the currentTarget.
event.currentTarget.dataset.value
```

So, when I call event.currentTarget.dataset.value in the stimulus controller I'm actually looking for data-value='xxx' from the selected option.  But, instead stimulus is looking for data-value on the target select menu.

How would I return the 'xxx' data-value attribute from the selected option when the target menu is changed?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1085810/2622934).  You should be able to use something like `event.currentTarget.options[event.currentTarget.selectedIndex]`.  Then read the data attributes there.

Comment: Thanks @cschroed.  That worked perfectly.  I knew it'd be easy.  If you wanna move that comment to an answer I'll mark it the one.

Comment: No problem.  Since this wasn't really directly related to an issue with Stimulus, I'm going to suggest that we close this question as a dup of the other more general one about getting at `<option>` elements.